# Percentages over column total avoiding warning

Tags: pandas

I am trying to get a new column with percentages over the total of another column without the warning regarding the copy/slice problem,

So "data" table is in place, so I want to add a new column "%" which is the percentage of m€ over total m€...

```
data_assets["%"] = data_assets["m€"]/data_assets["m€"].sum()
```

[image: data table]

It looks like it's working but would like the workaround for the warning.

Comment: Did you get the data_assets by filtering a data frame beforehand? I.e. did you do something like `data_assets = df[df.m > 500000]` ? If yes, you should try making a copy out of it, i.e. `data_assets = df[df.m > 500000].copy()`. This should get rid of the warning.

Comment: I love you!!! lol. It worked I did not try .copy() on the actual filtering

Really appreciate your help!

pd. BTW what does .copy() do exactly?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.